# Is there a SNS spring cloud stream module

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, amazon-sns

I recently started looking at spring cloud streams.  Is there a streams module that would allow us to talk directly through Amazon SNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not currently a module, but Spring Integration has an extension project that [supports SNS](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws) so it shouldn't be too hard to create a custom module.

Consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons#contributing).

The inbound adapter is available and there is a [pull request for an outbound adapter that's not merged yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/pull/19).

**EDIT**

The oubound adapter is now on master and available in the 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT - we will create a milestone release shortly.